# Can any one explain opencart session in API module?

Tags: php, session, opencart

Session not showing while dump the following session value.

`print_r($this->session->data['api_id']);die;`

*in api/cart/add module*.

Answer (score 0):

session variable api_id is set from the admin side. When the admin create or modify any order it create the different session for API user by api login. Check
**admin/controller/sale/order.php** file

Comment: Thanks for your kind response, but I have to work on API part, after API login I'm going to add the cart using add/cart API that time it returns `{"error":{"warning":"Warning: You do not have permission to access the API!"}}` It was checked by `http://localhost/`

Comment: During add to cart you will have to pass the api_token of that user from which you have done API login. API user can be added from system/user/api. In API login you can return his generated token for further queries.